# How to show text only when hovered over in questions?

Tags: feature-request, support, design, spoilers

On the site for puzzels, we always use the invisible text to hide spoilers. Unless hovered over, the text is yello, just as is the background.

However, I noticed that this feature doesn't work in the question itself, only in the answers.

Can I somehow make it work even in the answers's body?

> This text should not be visible.

and also...

> !Neither should this. Do not edit.
>   * We're looking for a common everyday object.
>   * It's not anything abstract as *love* or *energy*.
>   * It's not symbolic as *the letter A* or *peace sign*.

Comment: The text you put in the spoiler is invisible to me unless I hover over it. Are you saying it isn't for you?

Comment: That's weird... It's invisible to me too. However, [in this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/i-can-be-quite-bright-but-im-never-right-can-you-guess-who-i-am) it's not. I've made editions to it but when I had the hiding there, it wasn't active. Try it yourself...

Comment: Can you refresh and tell me what you see?

Comment: If you go to that link, you shouldsee that the text is visible right away, no hovering needed. That's what happens to me.

Comment: Oh, you mean the ordering markdown doesn't work in spoiler?

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the problem but as you can see in **this** question, I managed to reproduce the error. What am I doing wrong?! It seems that it works sometimes...